# Bootstrap datepicker autoset alone

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I need some help with bootstrap datepicker, I do not why, but when user press some key in keyboard, datepicker automatic fill the last day in month.

Comment: Can you share some code on how you create the datepicker, etc?

Comment: Hi, follow: 

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
 language: 'pt-BR',
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
 autoclose: true,
 todayHighlight: true  
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a default option from the datepicker to parse any input (alphabetic characters, wrong date formatting, etc) to the closest date to that input. So a letter will parse to the current date.

You can disable this behavior with the `forceParse` option

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
        autoclose: true, 
        todayHighlight: true,
        forceParse: false,
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zcvq0yhh/20/